# WordPress get post thumbnail and wrap it in permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to get the post thumbnail and link it to the post in WordPress. This seems logical to me but it's not producing the desired result.

```
<?php 
    if(is_category()){
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . '<img src="' . the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ) . '"</a>';
    }
?>
```

Instead, it's producing this in the DOM:

[image]

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>';
```

Comment: You might want to check the HTML source of the result. The 'get_the_post_thumbnail()' function actually returns an img tag with the post thumbnail URL inside, according to docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'get_the_post_thumbnail_url()' function? As described on this page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Also I'm not sure if the 'full' size is correct, maybe first try it without the optional size parameter. This only works while "in the loop", or you'll have to specify the post ID as the first parameter.

You might want to create an if statement to display the post tile if there isn't a post thumbnail (the function returns false if this is the case).

```
<?php 
if(is_category()){
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . '<img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ) . '"/></a>';
}
?>
```